# PythonAnywhere->ImportError raised loading nrpccms.newsroom.templatetags.blog_extras: No module named settings

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my very first app in [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/) (or at AnywhereAnywhere for that matter). I'm currently getting:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'blog_extras' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading nrpccms.newsroom.templatetags.blog_extras: No module named settings
```

[full error log](http://dpaste.com/1421863/)
[see error live](http://nimbiotics.pythonanywhere.com/)

The app newsroom is the very first one in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
#! python
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "nrpccms.newsroom",
    "django.contrib.admin",
# ...
```

`blog_extras.py` is at MY_PROJECT/MY_APP/templatetags and there *is* a `__init__.py` at MY_PROJECT/mY_APP.

Can you pinpoint my mistakes?

Comment: Can you post your `blog_extras.py` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I had to add my projects folder to sys.path in my wsgi script. This is my new wsgi script:

> activate_this =
>   '/home/nimbiotics/.virtualenvs/nrpccms/bin/activate_this.py'
>   execfile(activate_this, dict(**file**=activate_this))
>
> import os import sys
>
> path = '/home/nimbiotics/projects' if path not in sys.path:
>       sys.path.append(path)
>
> ##################################################### nrpccms_path = '/home/nimbiotics/projects/nrpccms' if nrpccms_path not
>
> in sys.path:
>       sys.path.append(nrpccms_path)
>
> #
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'nrpccms.settings'
>
> import django.core.handlers.wsgi application =
>   django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Comment: That's weird, normally if you create the project using the `django-admin.py`, the wsgi file created by it should have included your poject path.

Answer (score 1):

blog_extras.py is in the wrong folder

```
my_project/    
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
        templatetags/
            __init__.py
            blog_extras.py
```

**blog_extras.py** should exist in **templatetags** directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the **init**.py file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

[Official documentation on Custom Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)